# What is the difference between Google AdSense Native Ads and standard AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense

I want to know that what are AdSense Native Ads, and is there any difference in revenue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adsense Native Ads are the Latest Ad-styles by Adsense. These Ads have Two types: In-feed Ads and In-article Ads. Matched Content is also a type of Native Ads.

These Ads looks like your Blog, Article style, and Layouts. users more engaged with these types of Ads according to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Adsense Native Ads can display content that is similar to the content on your page. They can often look nicer than regular text based Adsense Ads, and the matching content can drive more click throughs.

The following link will help you set up native ads and will give you a better look at what the Native Ads program is about:

https://adsense.googleblog.com/2017/07/introducing-adsense-native-ads.html